How to define versioning strategy of software product including several modules with its own version?
Our software team has released software product several customers(B2B) continuously.
Software product includes several children modules(8EA) like below.
S/W Product: 0.0.0.0
  ㄴ Module A: 0.0.0.0 
  ㄴ Module B: 0.0.0.0
  ㄴ Module C: 0.0.0.0
  ㄴ ...

Not only S/W Product has its own version but Child modules also have their own version.
On updating modules or module, I always spend time to define new version of s/w product.
Is there any proper strategy s/w product versioning with several child modules?
